# Angular11 asyncvalidator custom validator error not added to reactive form errors list

Tags: rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I have a reactive form and adding a custom async validator to check if the values entered is unique by checking the array of available values. The validator is being invoked, but the validation error 'duplicate' is not getting added to the form field errors and not displaying in the template. Not sure what i am doing wrong here.

## component.ts

```
private registerFormGroup(): void {
        this.titleField = new FormControl(
            { value: this.auditTemplate.title, disabled: true },
            [Validators.required],
            [TemplateNameValidator.createValidator(this.auditTemplateService)]
        );

        this.templateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: this.titleField,
            tags: [this.auditTemplate.tags]
        });
    }
```

## name validator:

```
export class TemplateNameValidator {
    static createValidator(auditTemplateService: AuditTemplateService): AsyncValidatorFn {
      console.log("Static factory call");
      
      return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        if(isEmptyInputValue(control.value)) {
            return of(null);
        } else {
            return control.valueChanges.pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                switchMap((name: string) => 
                    auditTemplateService.isNameUnique(name)
                        .pipe
                        (
                            tap(response => console.log('inside switchmap', response)),
                            map(isUnique => !isUnique ? { 'duplicate' : true } : null),
                            catchError(() => of(null))
                        )
                )
            );
        }
      };
    }
  }

  function isEmptyInputValue(value: any): boolean {
      return value === null || value.length === 0;
  }
```

in the template html, if i try to display the error, it is not displaying anything:

```
<span>Duplicate: </span>{{templateNameField.errors?.duplicate}}<br>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AsyncValidators are used every time the `AbstractControl` state is changed, so you don't need to use the `control.valueChanges` observable.

Additionally, the observable you're returning from the validator function should send a complete signal after sending `null` or an error. If you return a hot observable, then the async validator will not work.

Try replacing `control.valueChanges.pipe(` with `of(control.value).pipe(`. Also, if your service method `.isNameUnique()` doesn't emit a complete signal, add `take(1)` before your the first `tap()` operator.

```
return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
  if (isEmptyInputValue(control.value)) {
    return of(null);
  } else {
    return of(control.value).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap((name: string) =>
        auditTemplateService.isNameUnique(name).pipe(
          take(1),
          tap((response) => console.log("inside switchmap", response)),
          map((isUnique) => (!isUnique ? { duplicate: true } : null)),
          catchError(() => of(null))
        )
      )
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Also, instead of using the if/else conditional, you can add `filter((name:string)=>!!name)` to the `of(control.value)` observable. The double bang will filter any falsy string values which include `null` and `""`.